# fetch request is not working while using react js and express js, Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am using react js and express js program. I have created express server, however my react js app is not working with my express js. I am showing you codes of react js below

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Get = () => {
  
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/posts")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((users) => {
            setUsers(users);
        })
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {users.map((post) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <p>{post.date}</p>
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default Get
```

It says

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch

and I think that it is connected with my fetch request.

This is the information in my server:

```
[
  {"_id":"617fa514d55c0cced18b1f6b","title":"New Title","description":"Hello World","date":"2021-11-01T08:26:52.000Z","__v":0},
  {"_id":"617fa52bd55c0cced18b1f6d","title":"New Title","description":"Hello World","date":"2021-11-01T08:26:52.000Z","__v":0},
  {"_id":"617fa52cd55c0cced18b1f6f","title":"New Title","description":"Hello World","date":"2021-11-01T08:26:52.000Z","__v":0}
]
```

Comment: on what host and port is your server up? CRA using http://localhost:3000 dy default. so i think you are using wrong url

Comment: can we use zoom, I will show you what is there

Comment: could you get data with post man ?

Comment: [You can proxy requests with CRA](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) which is probably what you need.